# Typed Lambda Calculus

Tags: type-inference, lambda-calculus

I want to find the type of the lambda expression `\x y -> x y y`. I proceed as follows.

1. We go in the reverse order of operations and "unpack" the expression. Assume the whole expression has type `A`. Then let `y` have type x1 and `\x y -> x y` have type `B`. Then `A = B -> x1`
2. We already know the type of `y`, and let `\x y -> x` be of the type `C`. Then `B = C -> x1`.
3. The type of `\x y -> x` is obviously `x1->x2->x1`. This is given to us in the previous exercise and makes sense because this expression takes in two arguments and returns the first.

Putting it all together we have that:

```
A = B -> x1 = C -> x1 -> x1 = (x1 -> x2 -> x1) -> x1 -> x1
```

The correct answer is somehow:

```
(x1 -> x1 -> x2) -> x1 -> x2
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I just write stuff's types under it and go from there:

```
foo = \x   y ->   x   y    y
foo    x   y =    x   y    y 
       a   b                 :  c
                  a   b    b :  c
                  a   b :  b -> c
                  a : b -> b -> c
foo : a -> b -> c
    ~ (b -> b -> c) -> b -> c
```

And another one:

```
bar = \x    y -> x (y   x)
bar    x    y =  x (y   x)
       a    b                        :  c
                 a (b   a)           :  c
                  ---------
                    b   a :  d
                    b : a -> d
                 a :         d       -> c

bar :  a -> b -> c
    ~ (d -> c) -> ( a       -> d) -> c
    ~ (d -> c) -> ((d -> c) -> d) -> c
```

But,

```
baz   x = x   x
      a   a   a :  b
          a : a -> b

baz : a -> b
    ~ (a -> b) -> b
    ~ ((a -> b) -> b) -> b
    ~ (((a -> b) -> b) -> b) -> b
    ........
```

is an "infinite" type, i.e. the process of type derivation never stops.

Comment: Very eloquent method. Does it work in general?
For example, I m now trying a very similar example \x y -> x (y x).
By your method, we have a (b a) : c => a : (b a) -> c and we are stuck? How do I go around this circular definition? Also if this algorithm has a name, could you please write it.